# Finding number of ways of selecting 6 gloves each of different colour from 9 pair of gloves?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are nine pairs of gloves each of different colors in how many ways can we arrange six gloves such that each is of different color?
I tried like this :
First number of ways in which we can select 6 colors out of nine it is $^9C_6$  ways. Then we can arrange it in 6! ways and also we can select either of two gloves out of the 6 in $2^6$ ways. Hence required number of ways should be $^9C_6$  .$2^6$.6!

Comment: Why are you permuting them?How is the order relevant?

Comment: @tushant sorry didn't meant to write select just edited!!

Comment: @Raghav.Then I think your solution is correct.

Comment: but answer is five digit number or less?

Answer (score 0):

How many ways can you select the first glove? 18
How many ways can you select the second glove? 16
How many ways can you select the third glove? 14
....
go on

Comment: so it is 18.16.14.12.10.8 = 3870720? But it is a very large number. The answer should be only 4-5 digits?

Comment: It is same as the answer given by Raghav.